# Palavras acentuadas não são enviadas ao banco de dados - PHP

Tags: php, sql

Fiz um formulário que envia dados de uma página php para um banco de dados e apenas os dados sem acentuação estão sendo enviados, se eu coloco um acento, nada daquele campo chega no banco de dados, nem sequer algo em branco.

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda

**Trecho do código:**

```
<textarea cols=\'20\' rows=\'10\' name=\'text\'></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar"> 

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){

$teste2 = $_POST['text'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `testes`(`texto`) VALUES ('".$teste2."');
```

Comment: Bom sobre os acentos resolvido colcoando um utf-8 enconde antes do $POST, mas agora caracteres como /, *. + não são enviados.

Comment: Pode postar seu código real? Esse código que vcoê colocou não devia nem executar, tem erros de sintaxe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certos símbolos não são aceites pois podem ser usados para entrarem na base de dados através de `MYSQL Injection`.

Uma forma de o fazer é usar `htmlentities` e `htmlspecialchars` que irão substituir esses simbolos pelo equivalente a html, ou seja:

```
$texto = htmlspecialchars(htmlentities($_POST['text']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Existem inumeras situações que podem fazer com que isso ocorra

> - A forma que você gerou sua tabela "unicode_utf8" ??
> - Como você está tratando suas strings?
> - Verifique se esta utilizando no utf8_encode e utf8_decode da forma correta.
> - Veja se esta utilizando filter_var() de  forma correta.
> - recomendo você tambem utilizar PDO para manipular dados é mais seguro.

Não sei se as barras eram nescessarias mais você pode fazer desta forma sem  ' \ '

`<textarea cols='20' rows='10' name='text'></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar">`